# Dúvida em Tabela SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, table

Criei uma tabela:

```
Tabela Curso:
Id int auto_increment
nome varchar;

Insert:
Default, Arquitetura;
```

Arquitetura ficou com o ID 1 na tabela.

Deleto o curso Arquitetura.

Quando eu adiciono qualquer outro curso,  ele assume ID = 2.

É possível fazer ele ocupar o ID = 1, que em tese está vago?

Comment: Não é uma boa ideia reaproveitar id, principalmente se tiver tabelas relacionadas.

Comment: A melhor prática é não deletar e sim marcar como excluído, inválido etc , recuperar a sequencia é ruim pois seria trabalhoso reordenar todas as tabelas dependentes como dito acima.

Comment: Faz total sentido o que vocês disseram. Vlw

Comment: A pergunta é "É possível fazer ele ocupar o ID = 1, que em tese está vago?" A resposta é SIM,  UPDATE Curso SET id='1' Where id='2'  porém contudo todavia ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gustavo, conforme comentários, não é aconselhável o reuso de código em uma coluna com auto-incremento.

Contudo, caso você se depare com uma situação em que é necessário reiniciar ou definir um novo valor de incremento, utilize o seguinte comando:

```
ALTER TABLE Curso AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

Nesse caso, os próximos registros inseridos na tabela Curso terão os Ids incrementados a partir de 1.

Você também pode alterar o Id de registros manualmente com um UPDATE, conforme comentado pelo Leo Caracciolo.

Caso a tabela já possua registros, sugiro que o valor de auto-incremento definido seja o MAX+1 da coluna, evitando assim a violação da restrição de unicidade na inserção dos próximos registros.